# What is wrong with asking a question like this?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do I check if name exists in table before inserting into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177487/how-do-i-check-if-name-exists-in-table-before-inserting-into-mysql)

What is wrong with asking a question like this?

Comment: Only the downvoters can tell you why they voted, but I would assume they do so because it looks like a rather trivial problem that you could solve by investing some work into debugging your code.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking this because someone downvoted the question? If that's the case then the simple answer is "Because that person decided that they wanted to downvote it". Without being able to read minds, we can't tell you why it was downvoted and that's not a problem. If you want my impression of the question, I'm certainly no MYSQL expert but it seems as though you've said "I tried doing this and it didn't work, why?" which seems a little vague to me.

Comment: Were there any comments on your question that got deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the timeline on your posts:

[image]

Your post went through two [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review), the triage and first post queues, which exposes it to more users and possibly downvotes.

During that time and subsequent to this your posts has been [substantially edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57177487/revisions). People can be intolerant of grammatical and formatting errors on posts. By taking the time to care for how the post is presented and worded it demonstrates to people that you care about the quality of your work and do not expect people to fix things for you that you can fix yourself.

I've made some pointers for asking questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387921/3956566).