# How can I improve a question for first bounty

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty, question-quality

I will create a bounty for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134954/voice-over-not-focusing-on-uicollectionview), and will be my first one.

As the question did not received enough attention (only 12 views), I fear that the points will be wasted.

Does anyone have any tips on how to improve the question, so the risk will be lower?

Comment: Having the best written question in the world does not necessarily mean it will get more views. I can't actually see much wrong with this question, 12 views (now 25) means it obviously has a small target audience, but the bounty will attract more views, one thing I can suggest is including more things you have tried to assist the person trying to claim the bounty

Comment: That is what bounty for !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

I'd recommend the following checklist - some of which you've fulfilled.

### Formatting

Ensure it's well formatted. You can see from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57134954/revisions) a couple of us have tweaked your format. One thing that drives me to distraction is poorly formatted code. Presentation tells your readers you've taken the time and care about your post.

### Grammar

Always check grammar, for the same reasons as mentioned in formatting.

### A clear problem statement

The clear problem statement needs to be both made within the question title and then elaborated on within the question body.

### What have you tried?

Also include everything that you've tried. I cannot tell if you've done this. Any pieces of information you may have missed, include them and possibly any relevant links that may help build your case.

View it like you're trying to solve a puzzle and you're giving people as much information as possible to do so.

Last and not least **Check for duplicates.**